# OpenCV, reading user text input while an image is being displayed (using waitKey)

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm a bit stuck trying to get some user text input while using OpenCV.

I have developed an iterative program which opens an image, detects colors and displays them using standard `cv::imshow()` followed by the mandatory `waitKey()`. In this state, pressing any key should just process and display the next image.

The problem is I want to allow the user to optionally click the image displayed and input some text data. I tried to use `cin >> mystring` but it looks like the `waitKey()` is blocking the console, so anything i type is displayed but not took by `cin` as input UNTIL the waitKey ends. It is a problem since some times i would like to get more than one text input per image, so it would be nice to be able to use console and cin normally while waitKey is working.

¿Any idea on how to allow a user to input text while an image is being displayed? A solution to my problem would be nice, but any other idea or workaround is also welcomed.

Ty!

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure if there's a direct method for getting strings. What if you set a mouse callback (for when the user clicks an image) and `cin` a string there?

Comment: @a-Jays This is exactly what i have tried. I am calling cin on mouse click, and the problem is that console (terminal) seems to be blocked by waitKey()

Comment: @a-Jays I have edited the question, because even when the console doesn't seem to respond to cin, if i switch  back to the windows and press any key, then the waitKey ends and the cin takes the input. Some thread blocking is going in here, will check the opencv source code.

Comment: I think waitKey() is a blocking operation, you would need to run your GUI updates on separate threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea about what you might be doing wrong - it would be great (for others landing here) if you posted your code too.

Like I suggested, you can set a mouse callback and get the string in that function. This worked fair enough for me:

```
std::string s("empty");
void on_mouse_click( int event, int x, int y, int, void* )
{
    if( event == EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN )    //are you missing this?
    {
        std::cout<<"enter string: ";
        std::cin>>s;
    }
}
int main()
{
    :
    :
    cv::imshow( "images", frame );
    cv::waitKey();
    std::cout<<s;
return 1;
}
```

The last display statement displays "empty" if I just hit a key directly. In case I click the image first, go back to console and type something, go back to image window and then hit a key, I get the string I enter instead.

Comment: Sorry for not posting code. This is exactly what I am doing. My problem is that as you say, after you type you need to go back to the window and hit a key. This solution only allows 1 text input per image. I would like to use cin normaly (read a string until you press space/enter), since for some images i expect the user to input several strings.

Comment: Can you try resetting a set global flag in the callback, and doing `while( flag && !waitKey() );` in main? It works for me in the exact way you want, but is a crappy solution.